# Why is the origin of the widget constantly at top-left when I use Transform.translate for the widget in my code?

Tags: flutter

I'm writing a flutter program in which you can move a widget with your finger by using **GestureDetector** instead of **Draggable** Widget.

Here is my code. I use **Transform.translate** to move.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AAA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AAAState createState() => AAAState();
}

class AAAState extends State<AAA> {
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(x, y),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
          RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
          final localOffset = getBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
          setState(() {
            x = localOffset.dx;
            y = localOffset.dy;
          });
        },
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Text('Button'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
//Actually I'm using AAA widget in a List like this.
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              children: widgetList,
            ),
          ),
```

But in my code, when I move the widget with my finger, the origin of the widget is constantly fixed at top-left.
I tried using **Transform** instead of **Transform.translate** and changing **origin:** property, but it wasn't going well.

Like this:

[gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIXw8.gif)

I want the origin to be at the position where I touched first.
Sorry for my poor English, but give me some advice!

Comment: use `details.delta` like: `offset += details.delta` and pass it to `Transform.translate` as `offset: offset`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I saw your advice and wrote like "offset = localOffset + details.delta;" , but it wasn't going well too. The result was same...

Comment: `offset += details.delta`

Comment: Oh, yes! I tried `offset += details.delta` and my program was going well! Thanks a lot.